# Unit tangent vector on points of a closed surface (e.g. ellipsoid)

Tags: analytic-geometry, vector-analysis

Assuming that we know the normal unit vectors on the points of a closed surface such as an ellipsoid, is it possible to find the corresponding tangent unit vectors on the same points?

Comment: You can find the tangent plane and then all lines passing through the given point and lying in the plane is tangent to some level curve.

Comment: Ok understood, but how can I find this plane? Is there any reference? Have in mind that i am trying to implement this on MATLAB and the surface is expressed via parametric equations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you know a normal unit vector $[A, B, C]$ and want to find the coordinates of a tangent unit vector $[p_1, p_2, p_3]$. As these two vectors are orthogonal, their dot product must be zero:

$$ [A, B, C] · [p_1, p_2, p_3] = 0 $$

$$ Ap_1 + Bp_2 + Cp_3 = 0 $$

Basically, that's all. Here $A, B, C$ are the coeffitients and $p_1, p_2, p_3$ are the unknowns. You can express any unknown coordinate (if its coefficient is non-zero) through the other two, and then plug in arbitary values for them to get a tangent vector, for example:

$$ p_1 = \frac{-Bp_2 - Cp_3}{A} $$

let  $p_2 = 2, p_3=5$,  then  $p_1 = \frac{-2B - 5C}{A}$

To make it a unit vector, simply divide each coordinate by the length of the vector, which is $\sqrt{p_1^2 + p_2^2 + p_3^2}$

Comment: Ok this may lead to something. I need two tangent vectors for each normal vector on an ellipsoid. One of the tangent vecotrs will be horizontal (no z component) and the second one i need it to be vertical to the first one i.e. forming something like a cross. What i understand from your method is that for the first one i will set p3=0 right? What about the second one?

Comment: Yes, for the horizontal vector you pick $p_3=0$. If I understand you correctly, you want all three vectors to be pairwise orthoganal, i.e. intersect at 90-degree angle. You can achieve that by finding the third vector $[q_1, q_2, q_3]$ as thee cross product of the first two: $[q_1, q_2, q_3] = [A, B, C] × [p_1, p_2, p_3]$ = $[Bp_3 - Cp_2, Cp_1 - Ap_3, Ap_2 - Bp_1]$ and then again dividing each coordinate by the length of the vector.